# Load local xml file asynchronous in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xslt

I m trying to load a local xml/ xsl file to a variable for editing. Following code works with IE and chrome . But chrome gives an warning since this call is synchronous.

```
function loadXMLDoc (file name){ 
   If (window.ActiveXObject){
      xhttp = new       ActiveXObject(“Msxml2.XMLHTTP”);
   } else {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  xhttp.open(“GET”,filename, false); // false is synchronous 
  xhttp.send();
  var xml = xhttp.responseXML;
  return xml;  
}
```

But if I make this asynchronize by changing this call.

```
xhttp.open(“GET”,filename, false);
```

To true

```
xhttp.open(“GET”,filename, true);
```

or call default.

```
xhttp.open(“GET”,filename);
```

It doesn’t work in chrome and gives error in the console.

original code works in IE but not working in chrome.

I want to fix this function or write a different method which can load an local xml / xsl asynchronous and get xml/xsl to a variable In chrome.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean, which error do you get exactly?

Comment: If you want asynchronous loading use the `onload` handler of course. Also which versions of IE do you target that you try for `window.ActiveXObject` and `ActiveXObject(“Msxml2.XMLHTTP”)` first?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load XML for XSLT processing then, to cater for IE, if that is needed, I think you can set `xhttp.responseType = 'msxml-document'`.

As for asynchronous processing and "returning" the document, consider promises e.g.

```
  function loadDoc(url) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve) {
         var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
         req.open("GET", url);
         if (typeof XSLTProcessor === 'undefined') {
           try {
             req.responseType = 'msxml-document';
           }
           catch (e) {}
         }
         req.onload = function() {
           resolve(this.responseXML)
         }
         req.send();
       });
  }
```

then you can do e.g. `loadDoc('sample.xml').then(function(doc) { ... })` or for both XML and XSLT

```
Promise.all([loadDoc(xmlUrl), loadDoc(xslUrl)]).then(function(data) {
      var xmlDoc = data[0];
      var xslDoc = data[1];
```

Promises are not supported natively in IE but can be added by a polyfill

Comment: The code I mentioned is working for IE. So I am good with IE. But as I mentioned this code doesn’t work for chrome. Do you know any solution for chrome browser ?

Comment: @Aka, the code you posted, with those non-ASCII quotes and an `If` instead of an `if` will hardly work with any JavaScript implementation. As for Chrome, the code I posted should work there, Promises are supported there in any case. What is not clear is what you are looking for exactly, if you expect to use asynchronous programming but to rely on the sequential, imperative programming style to " load an local xml / xsl asynchronous and get xml/xsl to a variable" you would need to use `await`, otherwise you need to use event handlers at least or Promises, as shown.